# How to get the variance of the residual variance in a simple linear regression model

Tags: regression, self-study, variance

How do you get the variance of the residual variance in a simple linear regression model? In a book I see that ${\rm Var}(S_R^2)=\frac{2\sigma^4}{n-2}$, where $S_R^2=\sum\frac{e_i^2}{n-2}$ and $e_i=y_i-\hat{y}_i$. How can I get this result?

I already know that $\frac{\sum e_i^2}{\sigma^2}\sim\chi^2_{n-2}$, but I need to know how I get the variance of $S_R^2$.

Comment: Could you add the [self-study tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)? I think it applies here.

Comment: Hint: the variance of a $\chi^2_{n-2}$ distribution is $2(n-2)$.  That's the only additional information you need.

Comment: Have you visited the [Wikipedia page on the $\chi^2$ distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution)? It contains all the relevant items of information.

Comment: @gung: you beat me to editing the title!

Comment: @Xi'an, at first I thought the OP was asking about the SE of $R^2$, then I thought it would be better to phrase it slightly differently. It's comforting to know that you were thinking along the same lines.

Comment: @will198, if you've figured it out, why not answer your own question?

Comment: Sorry. $\frac{\sum e_i^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{n-2}$ and knowing that $var(\chi^2_{n-2})=2(n-2)$ I can get that $var[\frac{\sum e_i^2}{\sigma^2}]=2(n-2)$ dividing for $(n-2)^2$ and multipliying for $\sigma^4$ I get $var[\frac{\sum e_i^2}{n-2}]=\frac{2\sigma^4}{n-2}=var[S_R^2]$. I applied that $a^2 \cdot Var(x)=var[a \cdot x]$

Comment: Maybe you could post this as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 4):

With:

- $\frac{\sum e_i^2}{\sigma ^2}\sim \chi^2_{n-2} $
- and knowing that $var(\chi^2_{n-2}=2(n−2)$
- I can get that $var[\frac{\sum e_i^2}{\sigma ^2}]=2(n−2)$ dividing for $(n−2)^2$ and multipliying for $\sigma^4$ I get $var[\frac{\sum e_i^2}{(n-2)}]=\frac{2\sigma^4}{n-2}=var[S^2_R]$. I applied that $a^2 \cdot Var(x)=Var[a \cdot x]$